# What is the best way to declare bootstrap-vue buttons?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

According to the bootstrap-vue docs a button is created like this:

```
<b-button variant="success" >Button</b-button>
```

But standard bootstrap syntax also works and renders the same way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
```

To my mind the second one is better because there is no bootstrap-vue specific syntax and hence will be easier to change later if need be, so, is there any reason not use '<button class=...>' rather than '<b-button variant=...>'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could just use Bootstrap (rather than `bootstrap-vue`) and follow the second approach you described for all elements. I suppose the benefit of `bootstrap-vue` is that elements are componentized so that you can add fewer classes to your HTML. It takes advantage of the more declarative style of programming which Vue offers, where you don't need to explicitly describe the behavior you want to see - it has already been abstracted out into components via the `bootstrap-vue` library.

I would suggest following a consistent approach whatever you do - e.g. if you are using `bootstrap-vue` in your project, use the Bootstrap components everywhere (as in the first approach you described).